# Access of services using Android SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, android

My school has a really strict firewall, and I can bypass it using the [SSH Tunnel app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sshtunnel)  connecting to my Linux VPS. They blocked the default SSH port 22, then I changed my SSH port to 80. It works fine, but just for the browser and some apps. I want to play some online games and chat on [Kik Messenger](http://kik.com), such they are ports 3993 (game) and 5222, 5223 (kik).

I guess the problem is in my VPS because when I am at home and connected with the [SSH Tunnel app for Android] and can't play and chat on Kik. But if I disconnect, it works fine.

Comment: in both place the ssh tunnel works fine just for the browser. I want to use apps and play games online and some games or app which don't use port 80 don't work. (ex. Clash of Clans uses port 3993 and does not work)

Comment: I dont use a command, I use an app called "SSHTunnel" for android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're doing it now, but I know that you can use dynamic port forwarding with SSH to turn your SSH client into a SOCKS proxy, which applications can be configured to use.

On Linux you can use `sudo ssh -D 1080 [your server here]` to open a SOCKS5 proxy on your localhost on port 1080. On Windows, you can use PuTTY; go to the Tunnels settings category as shown in the image below, and add a Dynamic port forward.

Configuring applications to use a SOCKS proxy varies depending on the application. Use localhost as the hostname, and whatever port you selected as the port when configuring applications.

[image]

Of course I have to mention the obligatory "It's probably against your schools AUP", yadda yadda yadda. Just be careful, and don't access inappropriate content at school via your tunnel.

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I will take my notebook to my school and see if it works. But, is there a way i can do this and forward all the ports on my Android Device?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea about Android. I didn't realize you were talking about a mobile device until after I typed my answer.